# Auto Layout Issue with UICollectionView and iPhone 5

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, autolayout, collectionview

I have a uicollectionview with cells that contain an image view laid out using constraints, but I have a problem.

If I execute the code on an iPhone 6(or major) I see the collection view fine, but on an iPhone 5 I don't see the images.

iPhone 6 screen:

[image]

iPhone 5 screen:

[image]

Autolayout (FotoProfilo is the imageview)
[image]

Can you help me?

Comment: Did you try to change the size of iOS simulator? Sometimes it helps

Comment: Are you implementing the _sizeForItem_ method? Do you see any message in the debugger about breaking the constraints that cannot be satisfied?